# Prevenir que input tenha texto por defeito

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Como faço para prevenir que ao abrir um formulário, os inputs estejam vazios e não tenham texto por defeito.

Basicamente o que pretendo é que os inputs estejam sem qualquer valor associado.
Neste caso a password já lá está, mas queria que estivesse sempre vazio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E ao escrever que não apresentasse a lista de opções escritas anteriormente. (como na imagem abaixo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso depende das configurações do navegador. Seu navegador provavelmente está salvando as opções de preenchimento. Altere essas configurações e o problema estará resolvido.

Comment: Mas assim não me garante o que eu quero para os utilizadores.
O quero é prevenir esta situação para todos os utilizadores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

olá você já utilizou JQuery? veja como é fácil solucionar seu problema com ele.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('input').val('')
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="password" value="123" placeholder="digite sua senha"  autocomplete="off" />
            <input type="text" value="oie" placeholder="digite um texto"  autocomplete="off" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

no exemplo que utilizei, toda vez que carregar/abrir a página os campos serão limpos, você pode adaptar o código como quiser.

O Placeholder = é para informar algo no campo para o usuário ler

O Autocomplete = é para ativar ou não a lista de informações já digitadas no campo
espero ter ajudado